# Get Bootstrap validation to fire before onclick event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't believe that this hasn't been answered before but I cannot find an answer if it has.

I have the following form:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="inviteme">Invite Me!</button>
</form>
```

If I click the submit button the validation works fine. However, if I add the following:

```
$("#inviteme").on('click', function () {
    //do something here;
});
```

Then the validation doesn't fire.

Is there a way to call the validation from the onClick event or another way of ensuring that the validation gets called before the click event is processed?

Comment: Since it's a `type="submit"` button, the form is submitted before the validation fires... Have you tried `function(event) { event.preventDefault(); // Then validate }`

Comment: Yes I have done that but the point is I don't know HOW to validate. What in Bootstrap do I have to call. I really don't want to have to rewrite all the validation as that would be a waste.

Comment: Hm. I see.I don't think Bootstrap has much in the way of validation (or at least I've never seen any). The `required` and `type="email"` are HTML5 attributes that prevent the submission of a form if those inputs violate those rules, but I don't think I follow what you mean about Bootstrap validations...

Comment: Tim is right, the only thing i've found is a project on github to avoid submisions until the form is valid, like abide in foundation.( https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator )

Comment: Pretty certain that this is standard Bootstrap isn't it? http://i.imgur.com/M6gRHu1.png or are you saying that is HTML5?

Comment: That element is HTML5, called when trying to submit an `input` with the `required` HTML5 attribute. It looks to be styled via Bootstrap though (which I didn't know was possible TBH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments the functionality is coming from HTML5 and not bootstrap so in order to validate across all browsers you have to write custom code or use a third party script.

Answer (score 0):

instead of .on('click') check,  [jquery .submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) , there you can validate and process the submit, cancel... etc.

Comment: See my comment above. I want to know how to call the Bootstrap validation not rewrite it.